# IndexError: list index out of range in python

Tags: python

Here is some code that I have written:

```
class MyClass:
    listt=[]
    def __init__(self):
        ""  

instancelist = [ MyClass() for i in range(29)]
for i in range(0,29):
    instancelist[i].listt[i].append("ajay")
print instancelist
```

I am getting this error:

```
File "/home/aj/workspace/PythonTutorials/basics/builtFun.py", line 16, in <module>
    instancelist[i].listt[i].append("ajaajayy")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What was that edit for?

Comment: Why are you creating a class that only contains a `list` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyClass:
    listt=[]
    def __init__(self):
        ""  

instancelist = [ MyClass() for i in range(29)]
for i in range(0,29):
    instancelist[i].listt.append("ajay")
print instancelist
```

Fixed.